# Helm: no chart version found

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I keep getting similar error even though the chart exists. Is it not SemV2 versioning?

**Error:**

```
The helm deployment failed because: Error: chart "ap983546-test-api" matching 2.0.0-featureesp2606-8 not found in artifactory index. (try 'helm repo update'): no chart version found for ap983546-test-api-2.0.0-featureesp2606-8
```

**Command Ran:**

```
helm upgrade ap983546-test-api artifactory/ap983546-test-api --set liveSlot=blue,blue.enabled=false,blueImage.tag=2.0.0-featureesp2606-6,greenImage.tag=2.0.0-featureesp2606-8 --wait -f charts/ap983546-test-api/values_rks.yaml --version 2.0.0-featureesp2606-8 --install
```

Comment: Have you tried the 'helm repo update' as suggested?